# Save ArrayList<ModelClass> of model class in shared preference android

Tags: android, json, arraylist, model, gson

I'm hitting API and getting saving its response in shared preference. I'm getting error on saving List in shared preference

API response :

```
club": {
    "username": "ADMIN",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
  },
  "channel": {
    "id": "QiExQlHA23rknooEYOVB",
    "previewTime": "158",
    "playlist": [
      {
        "playlist_id": "nJRYT001IEYb5Oj1eWiw",
      }
    ],
    "name": "donottouchit"
  },
  "**playlist**": [
    {
      "id": "nJRYT001IEYb5Oj1eWiw",
      "media": [
        {
          "name": "Doe Het Zelf zwemba.m4",
          "type": "video/mp4",
          "thumbnailPath": "mediafiles/2oHU5H3Pw62BgS8jNbl2/1628674169481_2oHU5H3Pw62BgS8jNbl2_thumbnail.jpeg",
          "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev-expo-sports.appspot.com/o/mediafiles%2F2oHU5H3Pw62BgS8jNbl2%2F1628674171950_Doe%20Het%20Zelf%20zwembad.mp4?alt=media&token=49742805-206b-46ab-b4e2-fca5ada4236b",
          "height": 1080,
          "width": 1920,
          "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev-expo-sports.appspot.com/o/mediafiles%2F2oHU5H3Pw62BgS8jNbl2%2F1628674169481_2oHU5H3Pw62BgS8jNbl2_thumbnail.jpeg?alt=media&token=9811078e-552e-424c-bceb-d10fe80045d8",
          "id": "AM8QE71IQ9sl3sXDA1TL",
          "duration": "37.719333"
        },
        {
          "name": "halee-burgess-mainphpAE8.jpeg",
          "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev-expo-sports.appspot.com/o/mediafiles%2FmX935y8INTI7A855VhxI%2F1630907577000_halee-burgess-mainphpAE8.jpeg?alt=media&token=496a62af-e200-426a-9c5f-0d161973269d",
          "id": "2NWBltMh2q1wdUaqEUuX",
          "height": 1024,
          "type": "image/jpeg",
          "width": 1024,
          "duration": "10"
        },
      
      ],
    }
  ],
```

Here I have got clubs and channel but getting issue in **PlayList** as its returning List.

This is how I'm getting its response and its getting proper data in list. I have printed the data

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("playlist");
List<PlayListModel> list =   gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonArray), new TypeToken<List<PlayListModel>>() {}.getType());
```

Function to save it in shared preference

```
String json = gson.toJson(list);
SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance().saveString(context,"playlistMediaData", json);

public void saveString(Context context, String sharedPrefName, String value) {
        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(value);

        prefsEditor.putString(sharedPrefName, json);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
```

Functions I tried to retrieve it :

```
 ArrayList<PlayListModel> PlayList = SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance().retrieveListJson(context,"playlistMediaData");

public ArrayList<PlayListModel> retrieveListJson(Context context, String sharedPrefName){
        ArrayList<PlayListModel> arrayItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String serializedObject = mPrefs.getString(sharedPrefName, "");
         if (serializedObject != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<PlayListModel>>(){}.getType();
             return arrayItems = gson.fromJson(serializedObject, type);
        }
         return  null;
    }

/*    public Collection<PlayListModel> retrieveListJson(Context context, String sharedPrefName) {
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<PlayListModel>>(){}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json = mPrefs.getString(sharedPrefName, "");
        Collection<PlayListModel> enums = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
        return enums;
    }*/
```

Other than that I have tried multiple ways but I get the same error every time

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.solis.expo.apiCall.ApiCallService.retrieveData(ApiCallService.java:145)
        at com.solis.expo.apiCall.ApiCallService.access$000(ApiCallService.java:30)
        at com.solis.expo.apiCall.ApiCallService$1.onResponse(ApiCallService.java:79)
        at com.solis.expo.apiCall.ApiCallService$1.onResponse(ApiCallService.java:49)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:100)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
```

I don't know whats I'm doing wrong but I couldn't understand the issue and Have tried almost all solution on stackoverflow
Thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save list in Shared Preference

```
 SharedPreferences  mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
JSONArray playlist = response.getJSONArray("playlist");
mPrefs.edit().putString("playlist",playlist.toString()).apply();
```

And to retrieve you list :

```
PlayListModel[] playListModels=new Gson().fromJson(mPrefs.getString("playlist",""), PlayListModel[].class);
    Log.d("tag",playListModels.toString());
```